# "Insufficient permissions" querying with Vue.js to Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm having problems querying Firestore with Vue.js.

This are my rules on Firestore:

```js
    service firebase.storage {
     match /databases/{database}/documents {
      match /users/{userid=**} {
       function getRole(role){
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.roles[role]
       }
       allow read, write: if getRole('admin') == true   
      }
     } 
    }
```

This is my structure, if I have to change it, it doesn't matter. I'm learning, I want to make the best practices:

```js
    -users[Collection]
      -userID[Document]
        -forms[Collection]
        -author: userID
        -name: "name"
        -roles: {
          -admin: true
        }
```

and this is the query that I'm trying with Vue.js:

```js
    usersRef.doc(`${this.user.uid}`).collection('forms').where('author', '==', true).get().then(snapshot => {
            console.log(snapshot)
          })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a typo. Instead of firebase, is firestore:

`service firebase.storage`

`service firestore.storage`.